# Java: Is it guaranteed that PatternSyntaxException won't be thrown during compile if Pattern.quote() is used?

Tags: java, regex

Just a simple question...
I'm trying to figure out whether I'm safe from PatternSyntaxException if I use the following expression:

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(someNotNullStringHere), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is safe. A `PatternSyntaxException` will not be thrown if you quote the entire input value.